# Can I validate, with HTML5 that 2 input[type=email] match?

Tags: html, forms, validation, input, match

is there any way to validate:

```
<input type="email" name="email1" />
<input type="email" name="email2" />
```

That email1 and email2 match? of course I could try with js and show some alert, but i would like to keep the html5 message system,

any chance?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there isn't anything in HTML5 to do that. You have to use JavaScript to achieve that, and don't forget to validate again on server side.